# Change of B > W in casual speech

Tags: phonology, consonants, bilabial

I am exploring the phonological system of Kyrgyz Language.

In casual speech people tend to change **b** > **w** when **b** occurs between two vowels or preceeds **l, r, y** and followed by vowel. Are there other languages where **b** changed into **w**? What may be the reasons for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common process called **lenition**.

Consider a language that has a phoneme /b/ as its only voiced bilabial phoneme. Speakers will then often pronounce /b/ without complete closure of the airway, giving a fricative [β] or approximant [β̞] realization.

A very similar phenomenon occurs in Spanish, Portuguese, and Catalan, where intervocalic /b/ is realized as [β̞]. For example, Spanish *bobo* /ˈbo.bo/ will be pronounced [ˈbo.β̞o]. Japanese similarly often realizes /b/ as /β/.

In this case, the (voiced bilabial) stop turns into an approximant. [Kyrgyz lacks a /w/ phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrgyz_language#Consonants), so there is no need to distinguish /b/ from /w/. Since the bilabial approximant [β̞] sounds similar to the bilabial-velar approximant [w], it is not surprising that [w] is another possible realization. Such shifting between various labial sounds and [w] is very common cross-linguistically; examples include:

- Ancient Greek /w/ (*Εὐρώπη* /ewrɔ̀ɔ́pɛɛ/) → modern /v/ (*Ευρώπη* /evˈro.pi/ 'Europe') (in the coda, before a voiced segment)
- Classical Latin /w/ (*vīvere* /ˈwiː.we.re/, 'to live') → Romance /v/ → Spanish /b~β̞/ (*vivir* /biˈbir/ [biˈβ̞ɪr] 'to live')
- Germanic /w/ (English *will* /wɪl/) → Dutch /ʋ~β̞/ (*wil* /ʋɪl/ 'want' 1sg), German /v/ (*will* /ˈvɪl/ 'want to' 1sg)
- Old Japanese /p/ (/pa/, topic marker) → /ɸ/ → modern /w/ (⟨は⟩ /wa/, topic marker) (sometimes)

Another such transformation is Ancient Greek *βῆτα* [bɛ́ɛ̀.ta] 'the letter beta' -> Modern Greek *Βήτα* [ˈvi.ta], where the /b/ was lenited to /β/, which was replaced with the cross-linguistically-more-common labiodental phone.

Comment: Korean also has lenition in the verb paradigm: some roots ending in -b such as 무겁다 *mugeop-da* have conjugated forms ending in -w like 무거워 *mugeow-eo*.

Comment: In Irish, the lenited form of /b/, written "bh", is pronounced /v/ or /w/ depending on dialect, from what I've read. I rather suspect that it is sometimes /β/, but I don't know that for sure. In Finnish, /p/ becomes /v/ when the syllable is closed.

Comment: The Japanese topic marker is written は but pronounced /wa/.

Comment: @jogloran: Fixed.