# Evolution of [v] to [b] and vice versa

Tags: phonetics, historical-linguistics, sound-change, phones

There are many examples that show that two phones [v] and [b] are related:

|  | b | v | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Old English to New English** | * ha**bb**an | ha**v**e | have |
| **Middle Persian to New Persian** | **v**aran | **b**aran | rain |
| **Middle Persian to New Persian** | **v**ehtar | **b**ehtar | better |

**Related to German **haben***

Besides, there is another relation between these phones.In the Cyrillic alphabet, the sign **B** is pronounced [V].

The phonetic characteristics of these two phones is as follows:

|  | Place of articulation | Manner of articulation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **v** | Labiodental | Fricative, Voiced |
| **b** | Bilabial | Stop, Voiced |

Given that they don't have much in common, I'd like to know:

- How is the connection between these phones justified?

Comment: The reason Cyrillic B represents /v/ is that the Cyrillic alphabet is based on Greek pronunciation from a time when /b/ had already shifted to /v/ (or at least /β/). Note that B (beta) is also pronounced /v/ in Modern Greek (where its name is _vita_). It’s likely that most cases of b>v or v>b go through /β/ as an intermediate stage (cf. Spanish where this is the synchronic stage currently).

Comment: English did not develop out of German; rather, both share a common ancestor.

Comment: If you don’t bother closing the lips when making a /b/, you make a /β/. If you then don’t bother using the top lip, only the bottom one, you make a /v/, which is acoustically similar to /β/ anyway. These are very frequent developments worldwide (along with the unvoiced counterpart, /p/>/ɸ/>/f/). You can keep leniting it further to /h/, then nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change of B > W in casual speech](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2982/change-of-b-w-in-casual-speech)

Comment: Middle Persiam wārān and wehtar had /w/ not /v/.

Comment: Not much in common? They share 2/3 of your chart, differing only in the unstable fricative vs. stop manner that easily undergoes fortition and lenition based on its environment. Oh, and that pesky "dental" part. But not many languages make a phonemic distinction there, and in fact some of them at some stages were a bilabial anyway even when spelled "v", as has persisted in Spanish today for example.

Comment: @LukeSawczak they have 1 in 3, the only common trait is being voiced.

Comment: @Coditoergosum The rest of my comment argues for the immateriality of the labiodental/labial distinction here. The overlap is very significant.

Comment: @fdb, yeah thanks, I think /w/ has merged to /v/ . Because in New Persian there is no /w/ and . Some dialects such as Kurdish have kept /w/ that  is equivalent of /v/ in Persian. Anyway the answer covered  all cases.

Answer (score 7):

The differences between [b] and [v] are fairly trivial between from a historical and phonetic perspective. The count of shared categories in the IPA chart isn't a good way of judging similarity (and the IPA doesn't claim to embody all relevant concepts of "category"). They are voiced oral labials: you can add "-dental" or "bi-" to be more precise. They are so similar that it is often hard to distinguish them.

Historical change operates by a series of changes, not leaps from Proto-X to Modern Y, and generally the progression is from [b] to something like [β] and [ʋ]. In some dialects of Tigrinya, /b/ becomes "[β]" in post-vocalic position, and this is optional but usually happens, but where it is extremely difficult to sharply categorize tokens as having [b] versus [β] (there is no contrast, you just have to look closely at the waveform). The difference has to do with the timing of the closure going into the consonant plus the total duration of the consonant, and very often it's a coin toss whether [b] or [β] is a better transcription.

Comment: *de babeporms, we habe to look closer.* (I got sinusitis)

Comment: What about the notion that aggriculture and soft food caused underbite which biased /p/ to /f/. Same for /b v/?